# Does a process invoking oom-killer kill itself?

Tags: kill, process-management, syslog

Looking through `syslog`, I see lines like `dd invoked oom-killer`.
Does this mean `dd` is being killed by the `oom-killer` or does it mean `dd` asked oom-killer to go kill another high memory process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dd` *triggered* OOM killer, which, in turn, [killed a process with the highest OOM score](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer).